# Github Clone Repo Error: warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout

Tags: git, github

I was attempting to copy `foo` repo into new `fooBar` repo. I am running into an error, here is what I did:

1. Created a new blank repo on github called `fooBar`
2. Manually created a copy of the `foo` folder (the repo I wanted to copy) in same dir as `foo` locally.
3. Renamed the copied`foo(Copy)` to `fooBar` locally.
4. `cd fooBar` and ran `git remote rm origin` as per [How to remove origin from git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224754/how-to-remove-origin-from-git-repository) (which might have been a mistake, because I am just using github, not git-svn)
5. Pushed my branch to my new remote `fooBar` repo like so:
   `git remote add origin https://github.com/myteam/fooRepo.git`
   `git push -u origin development` (Note that I used `development` instead of `master` - I thought `master` doesn't have any significance and is just a convention)
6. Finally I deleted my `fooBar` folder once I saw it has pushed to github successfully. I then tried pulling it
   `git clone https://github.com/myAccount/fooBar.git`

I then get the following:

```
Cloning into 'fooBar'...
remote: Counting objects: 9297, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1727/1727), done.
remote: Total 9297 (delta 7542), reused 9297 (delta 7542), pack-reu
Receiving objects: 100% (9297/9297), 1.58 MiB | 253.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (7542/7542), done.
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.
```

I can't find an answer for the highlighted error when cloning - everyone seems to have a problem when deleting a remote branch and trying to pull it.

> warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.

Note, in my new `fooBar` repo, `development` is the only branch and it's set `Default`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While cloning a repo `default branch is master`. But your `master` is [bare](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) (`no working or checked out copy of your source files`). All the codes are in `development` branch.

So, you need to mention `development` branch while cloning. Or, you need to push a `master` branch.

Try this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/myAccount/fooBar.git --branch development
```

Or,

```
 $ git clone https://github.com/myAccount/fooBar.git --branch development -b development --single-branch
```

Comment: That worked (the first one), can you explain why? I will accept the answer, but I am curious why git clone doesn't work without specifying the branch?

Comment: I pushed a master branch, deleted everything locally, and tried clone without the params again. Worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: I think sajib already answered this:  The repo you are cloning from does not contain a master branch, and the clone command defaults to trying to check out the master branch, which does not exist in this case.  Therefore, specifying development fixes the problem.

Comment: @VSO You can't `clone / pull / fetch` a bare repo. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys - all is good. I didn't know the 'master' branch had any significance. Assumed it would just clone from dev, but apparently not. I pushed a master branch and now git clone works.