# Can I force git to stay offline?

Tags: git

I want a bare, shallow clone of a git repo with no file contents, as all I'm interested in are the file paths themselves.  This works great:

```
$ git clone --bare --depth=1 --filter=blob:none --branch="118.0.5977.1" "https://github.com/chromium/chromium.git"
Cloning into bare repository 'chromium.git'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 34624, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (34624/34624), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (25673/25673), done.
remote: Total 34624 (delta 1647), reused 21869 (delta 1304), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (34624/34624), 13.72 MiB | 16.20 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1647/1647), done.
```

It completes in about 3 seconds, and takes up only 15 MiB on disk.  I can get the paths with `git ls-tree -r HEAD`.

**However**, various git commands seem to want to fetch additional data from the remote repo.  For example

```
$ cd chromium.git
$ git log
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (1/1), 372 bytes | 372.00 KiB/s, done.
commit 58a2c380702a84b362d0ee74ffc1e53e937770dd (grafted, HEAD, tag: 118.0.5977.1)
...
```

Can I tell git not to do this?  I would prefer the command to fail rather than fetch any additional data from the remote.

Comment: I do not have a lot of experience with bare/shallow repos _but_ it sounds like a contradiction that you do a shallow clone and then you try to run a `git log`. Also... if it is a bare repo, I would think that providing the branch you want to log makes sense.

Comment: Bare repos still have a HEAD, but anyway `git log 118.0.5977.1` does the same thing.  Also `git log` was just an example, it seems many commands (`git cat-file`, `git rev-parse`, ...) end up talking to the remote.

Comment: If I do `git remote remove origin` then `git log` says `error: unable to read mailmap object at HEAD:.mailmap`, which at least explains what it's looking for on the remote

Comment: It makes sense.... you did _a shallow_ and pulled no blobs.... you are asking to run a full race but you only got gas _vapors_ in the tank.

Comment: @eftshift0 Sure, but I would be very surprised if my car drove itself to the gas station... in this case, I'd rather it just stop once it runs out of gas

Comment: Is this what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224754/how-to-remove-origin-from-git-repository

Comment: @Joshua Not exactly, I'd like to keep the remote around so that an explicit `git fetch` works if I need it.  Anyway I found an explanation here: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone/.  `git config remote.origin.promisor false` does what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the relevant documentation at https://www.git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone/.  In particular,

> - Since almost all Git code currently expects any referenced object to be present locally and because we do not want to force every command to do a dry-run first, a fallback mechanism is added to allow Git to attempt to dynamically fetch missing objects from promisor remotes.
>
>   When the normal object lookup fails to find an object, Git invokes promisor_remote_get_direct() to try to get the object from a promisor remote and then retry the object lookup. This allows objects to be "faulted in" without complicated prediction algorithms.
>
>   For efficiency reasons, no check as to whether the missing object is actually a promisor object is performed.
>
>   Dynamic object fetching tends to be slow as objects are fetched one at a time.
>
> ...
>
> Remotes that are considered "promisor" remotes are those specified by the following configuration variables:
>
> - `extensions.partialClone = <name>`
> - `remote.<name>.promisor = true`
> - `remote.<name>.partialCloneFilter = ...`

So if there is a "promisor" remote, git will automatically fetch missing objects from it.  To make it not a promisor, all I have to do is

```
$ git config --unset remote.origin.promisor
$ git config --unset remote.origin.partialclonefilter
```

and it now gives errors like I want it to:

```
$ git log
error: unable to read mailmap object at HEAD:.mailmap
commit 58a2c380702a84b362d0ee74ffc1e53e937770dd (grafted, HEAD, tag: 118.0.5977.1)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

You've done a clone which is not only shallow (`--depth=1`), but partial (`--filter=blob:none`).  According to [the documentation](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone/), “[u]se of partial clone requires that the user be online and the origin remote or other promisor remotes be available for on-demand fetching of missing objects.”

If you don't want to have to be online at all times, then keep the shallow option, but re-clone without any `--filter` options, which will download just a single revision but avoid the need to be online.

Comment: This is explicitly not what I want.  I do want a partial clone.  I don't ever want to "download objects on demand" -- I want git to fail if that would be necessary.

Comment: A partial clone necessitates being online constantly to fetch objects on demand; that's built-in functionality.  If you want a partial clone that doesn't automatically try to fetch objects on demand, you want a feature Git doesn't provide.

Comment: It seems like I can get git to work that way after all, see my own answer