Prevent "git archive" from talking to remote
I have a CI job which does a shallow checkout like this:
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout $REPO .
git fetch origin $BRANCH
git checkout -f $COMMIT

I wanted to then archive that shallow copy of the repo as a tarball, so I did this:
git archive --format=tar --output=repo.tar HEAD

To my surprise this was not a completely local operation, it seems to be talking to the remote and downloading large objects (including LFS):
remote: Enumerating objects: 27903, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (14635/14635), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (12500/12500), done.
Receiving objects: 100% (27903/27903), 290.57 MiB | 22.74 MiB/s, done.
remote: Total 27903 (delta 3317), reused 2370 (delta 2135), pack-reused 13268 (from 1)
Resolving deltas: 100% (6309/6309), done. 40% (2524/6309)
Downloading {redacted} (78 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (57 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (59 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (2.0 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (2.3 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (1.2 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (2.3 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (1.8 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (3.3 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (4.2 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (3.5 MB)
Downloading {redacted} (5.7 MB)

I would like for git archive to just make an archive of what is present locally and not talk to the remote at all, is this possible?

Try git config --unset remote.origin.promisor && git config --unset remote.origin.partialclonefilter Found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77004074/7976758

@phd that definitely stops the download but it causes the command to exit with an error ... I'd like it to succeed and just archive whatever it has already fetched. Do you know if that's possible?

Not using git archive and just tar or zip the directory.
